# Outlook Android word suggestion not working in LG keyboard

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, outlook

I have an LG G3 phone with Android 6.0. It works okay, and I like the built-in LG Keyboard as it uses ***word suggestion*** (meaning that when I type *I lkie my dosg* it corrects every word, so I get *I like my dogs* in my native language - it is not English).

Recently, I've downloaded Outlook Android and tried to write an email to my co-worker.

Imagine my surprise when I wrote the following: *Dera Freind, This is teh new Andorid Outluk...* and no word were suggested in my LG keyboard.

There are no keyboard related settings in Outlook settings (as a matter of fact, those 3 settings don't relate anything other than the account).

When I type in the *subject* field, it works normally, but in the *letter body*, no suggestions appear.

So, can you tell my why Outlook *suppresses* the LG keyboard settings?

Can I enable word suggestion *without installing any custom keyboard*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reported the issue to Microsoft's feedback forum, and a few weeks later they fixed it and now it picks up the suggestions that the keyboard offers (I fancy that it was because of my report but can't confirm it :)

So, as of version **2.1.125 (170) mainline**, *the issue is fixed*.